# Is there a process to re-establish connection to CRM after refusal?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamics-crm

I have an app designed to sync data between two of our environments. Even though Dynamics CRM has a listed API limit of 4000 requests within 300 seconds, my connections are being refused after 49 - 500 calls depending on the protocol.

Is there some setting for MS Dynamics that would be restricting this? Or is there a way to re-establish a new connection after it is refused?

Comment: Hi, to help you there is number of information missing:
1) code snipped of how you're calling CRM 2) what exception are you getting. I can imagine two issues - either you're running into throttling limit (number of requests you can make per 5 minutes with the same user) or your authentication token is expiring (i.e. sync is long running task and you re-use the same token). 3) you're having perf problems (plugin executing on CRM side can only handle so much).

Comment: I'm using just ntlm authentication to get access to the CRM OData Web API. There isn't a specific plug in I'm connecting to, just the general REST endpoint. Then I'm using HttpWebRequest class to make PATCH calls to the service. Pretty standard REST work. The error I'm getting is a "connection refused error, Dynamics CRM has forcibly closed the connection"